# Spring jpa autocomplete is not showing up when i type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

Nothing shows up when i start typing find in spring boot jpa.
[image]

Comment: This feature is only available in Ultimate Edition. Are you sure you are not on Community Edition?

Comment: What version of Intellij are you using and have you enabled the proper plugins.

Comment: Yes I am using ultimate edition

Comment: did you solve it? if yes please say how

Comment: @MohammadBaqer I'm sorry but I can't recall, I think the first answer is correct and it had to do with the version of Intellij

Comment: @MohammadBaqer did you find an answer? If yes, pls let me know how you fixed this difficulty. I have same problem and cannot fix it for 6 monthes.

Comment: @MohammadBaqer I'm sorry but I can't recall exactly. I think it might have been something with the version of Intellij or the community/ ultimate edition. I'm not sure what else you can try since I stopped using the software after I finished working on this project.

Comment: @BahramAfandi its not available on Intellij Idea Community Edition and you must use Ultimate Edition

Answer (score 1):

I use Intellij IDEA CE and it never completed.

If I need some options out of the normal I look into the spring documentation to find the way to do what I need.

@Krisztian Toth may be wright and it only has that option in the UE.